# Is there a shorter way of doing this in python?

Tags: python

Is there a shorter way to perform an operation on each dictionary item, returning a new dictionary without having to first create an empty dictionary like i did?
**Note**: The original `a_dictionary` values should not be changed.

```
a_dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
result_dict = {}
result_dict.update((x, y*2) for x, y in a_dictionary.items())
```

Comment: Yes, the generator expression can be passed directly to `dict`.

Comment: A dict comprehension is more readable if you are *constructing* the key/value pairs, but I would prefer `dict(some_iterable)` over `{k: v for k, v in some_iterable}`.

Comment: @chepner Trying to use `dict(some_iterable)`, This is the best i can think of  `result_dict = dict(zip(a_dictionary.keys(), [x*2 for x in a_dictionary.values()]))`.

Comment: You already have the generator expression you want being passed to `result_dict.update`. Just pass it to `dict` instead: `result_dict = dict(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
result_dict = {x: y*2 for x, y in a_dictionary.items()}
```